# Optimisation using scipy

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, minimize

In the following script:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimise

a=np.array(range(4))
b=np.array(range(4,8))

def sm(x,a,b):
      sm=np.zeros(1)
      a=a*np.exp(x)
      sm += sum(b-a)
      return sm

 x0=np.zeros(4)
 print sm(x0,a,b) #checking my function

 opt = minimize(sm,x0,args=(a,b),method='nelder-mead', 
 options={'xtol': 1e-8,     'disp': True})
```

I am trying to optimise for x but I am having the following message:

> Warning: Maximum number of function evaluations has been exceeded.

And the result is:

> array([-524.92769674,  276.6657959 ,  185.98604937,  729.5822923 ])

Which is not the optimal. 
My question is am I having this message and result because my starting points are not correct?

Comment: Can anyone explain to me about the result?

Comment: There is more to the error message than you have posted:  `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/kernel/__main__.py:3: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in exp
  app.launch_new_instance()
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/optimize.py:456: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in subtract
  numpy.max(numpy.abs(fsim[0] - fsim[1:])) <= ftol):`

Comment: @AGS Indeed. Running it on Spyder IDE produces only the afore mentioned error. Running it in Canopy (after your comment) produces the error message that you have posted. A possible explanation to your opinion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function `sm` appears to be unbounded. As you increase `x`, `sm` will get ever more negative, hence the fact that it is going to `-inf`.

Re: comment - if you want to make `sm()` as close to zero as possible, modify the last line in your function definition to read `return abs(sm)`.

This minimised the absolute value of the function, bringing it close to zero.

Result for your example:

```
>>> opt = minimize(sm,x0,args=(a,b),method='nelder-mead', options={'xtol': 1e-8,     'disp': True})
Optimization terminated successfully.
         Current function value: 0.000000
         Iterations: 153
         Function evaluations: 272
>>> opt
  status: 0
    nfev: 272
 success: True
     fun: 2.8573836630130245e-09
       x: array([-1.24676625,  0.65786454,  0.44383101,  1.73177358])
 message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
     nit: 153
```

Comment: What I would like to achieve is to min((b[0]-a[0]*exp(x0))+(b[1]-a[1]*exp(x1))+(b[2]-a[2]*exp(x2)+(b[3]-a[3]*exp(x3)). What I am expecting is to have as a result 4 different **x** for each a. I will give you an example: for the pair (b[2]-a[2]*exp(x2))=6-2*exp(x2) I expect a result that gives exp(x2)=3. I change from exp(x) to exp(-x) but same warning.

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding your problem, but as you state it, `min((b[0]-a[0]*exp(x0))+(b[1]-a[1]*exp(x1))+(b[2]-a[2]*exp(x2)+(b[3]-a[3]*exp(x3‌​))` will be minimised for `x = [-inf, -inf, -inf, -inf]`

Comment: First of all, thank you.  `x0=-inf,x1=-inf,x2=-inf, x3=-inf ` will minimise my sm to inf. Probably my implementation is wrong. How can I have as a result from the optimization `x0,x1,x2,x3 ` so to minimum of sm will be close to zero?

Comment: See edited answer - you need to minimise the absolute value of the function.

Comment: Yes with that way I bound my function. However, so as to have the expected result that I want I replace: sm += sum((b-a)**2)

Answer (score 1):

Modifying the proposal of FuzzyDuck, I replace sm +=((b-a)**2) which return me the desired result.