# Minimizing a function in python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have a histogram  in python and I want to calculate the minimum of the sum(n[i]-gauss(x[i],sigma,mu))**2 where x[i] is the value of the bins[i] corresponding to n[i], and the minimum must be obtained by modifying sigma and mu (I don't want to use the ones obtained from fitting curve). So this is my program:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize
from random import gauss
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import norm
import math

values = []
while len(values) < 10000:
    value = gauss(0,20)
    if -100 < value < 100:
        values.append(value)


n, bins, patches = plt.hist(values, 10, facecolor='green',normed='1')

mu, std = norm.fit(values)

x=np.arange(-100,100,0.01)
y=1/(math.sqrt(2*math.pi)*std)*np.exp(-(x-mu)**2/(2*std**2))
plt.plot(x,y,"b-")

binWidth=bins[5]-bins[4]

def gauss(x):
    f=0
    for i in range(len(n)):
        centre=(2*bins[i]+binWidth)/2
        f=f+(n[i]-1/(x[1]*math.sqrt(2*math.pi))*np.exp(-(y[(centre+100)*100]-x[0])**2/(2*x[1]**2)))**2
    return f

x0=np.array([0.01,0.01])
res = minimize (gauss,x0,method='nelder-mead',options={'xtol': 1e-8, 'disp': True})

print res.x
```

So after running I should get the minimum of the function and the mu and sigma for this minimum (and it worked for other functions). But I get this warning: Warning: Maximum number of function evaluations has been exceeded. And I get some values for mu and sigma but they are different for each run, so something is wrong. What should I do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Optimisation using scipy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29229810/optimisation-using-scipy)

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev I don't think my sum goes to -inf...

Comment: Your primary concern is the warning, isn't it?

Comment: If you add `'maxiter': 200`, or whatever number of iterations you want for the cutoff, to the `options` dict, you might be able to run the optimization to convergence. (c. f. http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html#scipy.optimize.minimize)

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev well yes, because it gives me the wrong numbers

Comment: @Elliot I tried but i get the same warning (I even put 1000000 as a number) It might be another error?

Comment: Ok, then the other problem you're having is the tolerance. You're just not going to get down to machine precision with the function you got. If I set `xtol: 1e-2`, your code would run pretty consistently. Whether that's good enough for your purposes is up to you.